# How do I get the User ID of a discord user using discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im using Discord.py and Im trying to get the Discord userid of a user when they type into a channel.

The userid can be found when you go into developer mode, and right click on a username, there will be an option "copy id".

The current api is not saying how to do this, or I keep missing it

Answer (score 13):

The documentation says that the `User` class have the user's id:
http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#user

And that `Member` is a subclass of `User`:
http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member

So if you got a message from a user, you can get the id with `message.author.id`

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.author.id)

client.run('token')
```

Comment: Thank you, I have another question concerning discord's OAuth2. Im trying to get the user id using oauth2 but it is not returning it. I am using this plugin

https://github.com/teamreflex/oauth2-discord

Comment: @GibsLeFleur That's out of my knowledge, I'd recommend you to create another question about that

Comment: is there a way that i can get an id from an @username that is passed into a command funciton?